# Symbol not working on other computer

Tags: javascript, php

I have  symbol in my code which on my computer displays as it should but, on other computer instead of this I see `▯`.
What could happen?

My symbol is used in Javascript code but is stored in PHP variable.

**PHP**:

`$arrow = "";`

**JS**:

`text: "ONT[%] <?php echo $arrow; ?>"`

Comment: What font is being used? Is that symbol in the font used on the other computer? (Likely the default font set in the browser.)

Comment: Try setting `$arrow = '&#8593';`

Comment: Well, I think the font is default and I got this symbol by copying that arrow from site with Unicode Characters. Both are opened in Google Chrome

Comment: `$arrow = '&#8593';` doesn't work, it just prints `&#8593`

Comment: @rmirabelle I think the code also depends to the font which is being used.

Comment: I tried with several other arrows such as `     ` and none worked

Comment: I don't see those symbols in Chrome/Windows 7 if they are new unicode symbols they are not supported by all systems, the only think you can do is to use symbols that are supported or use image or font icon.

Comment: Other computer you mean by browser or operating system?

Comment: Browser on the other computer. Where can I get Windows 7 supported icons?

Comment: Check encoding scheme you are using, utf-8 or other

Comment: It is UTF-8, have it in my code

Comment: You can use '&#8593;' instead '&#8593';

Comment: I don't know what you mean, can't run PHP code without `;` at the end

Comment: sorry, meant to type `'&#8593;'` - notice the `;` is required as part of the string itself. In PHP: `$arrow = '&#8593;';`

Answer (score -1):

You should use a font icons library, so that you don't have to be dependent on different browsers or OS.

Below is the example for [Bootstrap Fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/examples/)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<span class="fa fa-arrow-up">Up</span>
<span class="fa fa-arrow-down">Down</span>
<span class="fa fa-arrow-left">Left</span>
<span class="fa fa-arrow-right">Right</span>
```

Comment: But I need to use it in PHP
Here's my code
`theme: "theme2",
                                  animationEnabled: true,
                                    title: {
                                        text: "MI[ppt] <?php echo $arrow; ?>"`

Comment: You can do this: `$arrow = '<span class="fa fa-arrow-up"></span>'`

Comment: It says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. 
I use this PHP variable in my JavaScript function
So I guess it goes like `HTML->PHP->JS`

Comment: Take care of the strings, that is what throwing the error.